# Can I make a django forms ChoiceField scrollable?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a ChoiceField drop down menu in Django form. It has times from 9:00 AM up until 5:30 PM - about 18 items. When someone clicks on the drop down, it shows all the values at once. What I'd like it to do is show only about 3 or 4 values with a scroll bar to the right, so that the user can do the scrolling. The reason I want it this way is because it takes less space and looks better. Anyway to get this going? This is what I have so far:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
        ('1', '9:00AM'),
        ('2', '9:30AM'),
        ('3', '10:00AM'),
        ('4', '10:30AM'),
        ('5', '11:00AM'),
        ('6', '11:30AM'),
        ('7', '12:00PM'),
        ('8', '12:30PM'),
        ('9', '1:00PM'),
        ('10', '1:30PM'),
        ('11', '2:00PM'),
        ('12', '2:30PM'),
        ('13', '3:00PM'),
        ('14', '3:30PM'),
        ('15', '4:00PM'),
        ('16', '4:30PM'),
        ('17', '5:00PM'),
        ('18', '5:30PM'),
    )

    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

[image: Missing scroll bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a built-in browser control; there's no way to make it scrollable. The only thing to do is to replace it with a custom Javascript widget. You might want to investigate [select2](https://select2.github.io/) which does exactly this; there's a [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which implements a form widget you can use in your own forms.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can, implementando js library: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

You modify css by height you want

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}